# Hide / show on condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide and show a button on a particular condition in JavaScript.

Code:

```
$(function(){
    // hide the div initially
    $("#a").hide();

    // Check to see if there is 250 in the url
    var bal_amount = document.getElementById('balance_amount');
    if (bal_amount.value > 0) {
        $("#a").show();
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="balance_amount">
</form>

<image src="image.jpg" id="a">
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Are you trying to validate the `balance_amount` in a text field when focus changes, and then show your link?

Comment: Would be really helpful to see your HTML. It is possible that `bal_amount.value` is < 0

Comment: Are you sure you want to select the div with `id="a"`? Seems a strange id.

Comment: probably `parseInt` the value...also, it may be nicer to just do `$('#balance_amount').val()` if your using jQuery anyways

Comment: @Jivings:  yes. I want to select div with id="a". Actually it is a image not a div with id="a"

Comment: I have edited the code in the question. You can see the html code there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change this portion of your code -

```
// Check to see if there is 250 in the url
var bal_amount = document.getElementById('balance_amount');
if (bal_amount.value > 0)
{
    $("#a").show();
}
```

You are executing the above piece of code inside `document ready` event, which means it will be executed right when the page loads, and only once.

To remedy this, you need to place this code inside an event handler -

```
​$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#a").hide();

    // See this? This is the event handler for the
    // change event which will fire whenever the value
    // of the text box changes.
    $('#balance_amount').change(function () {
        // Check to see if there is 250 in the url
        if ($(this).val() > 0) {
            $("#a").show();
        }
    });
});​
```

In this way, whenever the value of the `balance_amount` field changes, this event will trigger and validate your balance amount for your.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/f5Ppa/) you will find a working demo.

You can further improve your code by checking for invalid input in the text box -

```
​$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#a").hide();

    // See this? This is the event handler for the
    // change event which will fire whenever the value
    // of the text box changes.
    $('#balance_amount').change(function () {

        var balance = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        if (isNaN(balance)) {
            alert('You have entered an invalid value');
            return false;
        }

        if (balance > 0){
            $("#a").show();
        }

        // There you go, an else block for you
        else {
            $("#a").hide();
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: It works but the problem is that it works when I type the value in the text box but the value of textbox comes automatically and that's why it not works when the value of text box comes automatically. and I also want else statement here.

Comment: @user1814328: You can easily include `else` statement here! Also, the change event fires only when the focus goes out from the text box. The alternate will be to check for `keyup/down` events, which probably you don't want.

Comment: @user1814328: Why do you want to use `else` statement? I have shown an example of `else` in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#a").hide();
   $('#balance_amount').keyup(function () {
        // Check to see if there is 250 in the url
        var bal_amount = $('#balance_amount').val();
        if (bal_amount.value > 0) {
            $("#a").show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: there is an error in line 3 ($({selector for input box}).bind('input propertychange', function() {)

Comment: I really don't like the mixture of jQuery and document selectors.